How make multiple when condition on polars
I have a dictionary with strings as keys an polars expresions as values.
How can I do something like this in a concise way:
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(condition_1)
    .then(pl.lit(key_1))
    .when(pl.lit(condition_2))
    .then(pl.lit(key_2))
    ...
    .otherwise(None)
    .alias("new_column")
)


Are you saying that you have my_dict = {"value_1": condition_1, ...} and you want to convert it into a when/then chain? (If so, maybe you can show a full minimal example to clear that up.)

@jqurious yes precisely that!

Consider the following example data.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "num": list(range(6)),
})

shape: (6, 1)
┌─────┐
│ num │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
│ 2   │
│ 3   │
│ 4   │
│ 5   │
└─────┘

In general, pl.when().then().otherwise() constructs can be nested to obtain the effect of a switch statement, which you seem to outline in your question.
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("num") < 2
    ).then(
        pl.lit("small")
    ).otherwise(
        pl.when(
            pl.col("num") > 3
        ).then(
            pl.lit("large")
        ).otherwise(
            pl.lit("medium")
        )
    )
)

shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────────┐
│ num ┆ literal │
│ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ str     │
╞═════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ small   │
│ 1   ┆ small   │
│ 2   ┆ medium  │
│ 3   ┆ medium  │
│ 4   ┆ large   │
│ 5   ┆ large   │
└─────┴─────────┘

This can be tedious if many conditions are nested. In this case, pl.coalesce might help together with the fact that a pl.when().then() construct evaluates to null if the condition in pl.when() is not satisfied.
df.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        pl.when(pl.col("num") < 2).then(pl.lit("small")),
        pl.when(pl.col("num") > 3).then(pl.lit("large")),
        pl.lit("medium")
    )
)

shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────────┐
│ num ┆ literal │
│ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ str     │
╞═════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ small   │
│ 1   ┆ small   │
│ 2   ┆ medium  │
│ 3   ┆ medium  │
│ 4   ┆ large   │
│ 5   ┆ large   │
└─────┴─────────┘

If you have a dictionary with values as keys and the conditions as values, this might be used as follows.
d = {
    "small": pl.col("num") < 2,
    "medium": pl.col("num") < 4,
    "large": pl.col("num") >= 4,
}

df.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        pl.when(cond).then(pl.lit(val)) for val, cond in d.items()
    )
)

